# Confidence interval for a Pearson Correlation Coefficient between two distributions which are not iid

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, correlation, confidence-interval

I have two distribtions $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, and I find the Pearson Correlation Coefficient $\rho$ between them. I want to calculate a confidence interval/uncertainty on the value of $\rho$, and the Wikipedia article for $\rho$ says this can be done using the Fisher transformation, but is only valid if the sample pairs are iid. Is it possible to calculate the confidence interval on $\rho$ if the sample pairs are not iid?

Comment: Are you looking at a sample? If so, you might consider bootstrapping.  If not, why is there any uncertainty?

Comment: @Henry I have a true distribution that I'm attempting to estimate with a model. If I have two different models, with two different correlations with the true distribution, I want to be able to discriminate whether one is truly more correlated with the true distribution, or whether there is simply random noise in the model which makes one correlation higher than the other.

Comment: @Henry I know that the samples in the model distribution are not iid